# What is the best way to store anciliary data with a 2D timeseries object in R?

Tags: r

I currently try to move from matlab to R.

I have 2D measurements, consisting of irradiance in time and wavelength together with quality flags and uncertainty and error estimates.
In Matlab I extended the timeseries object to store both the wavelength array and the auxiliary data.

What is the best way in R to store this data?

Ideally I would like this data to be stored together such that e.g. window(...) keeps all data synchronized.

So far I had a look at the different timeseries classes like ts, zoo etc and some spatial-time series. However none of them allow me to neither attach auxiliary data to observations nor can they give me a secondary axes.

Comment: Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure what you want, but here is a simple tutorial mentioning 
R's "ts" and"zoo" time series classes:

http://faculty.washington.edu/ezivot/econ424/Working%20with%20Time%20Series%20Data%20in%20R.pdf

and here is a more comprehensive outline of many more classes(see the Time Series Classes section)

http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/TimeSeries.html

Comment: I am aware of those classes. However, I would like to have two more things,
First, use a second axes, in this case wavelength and 
second, attach auxiliary data to the timeseries like quality flags, noise estimates etc. such that they also get treated correctly by for e.g. the window function.

Anyway, thanks for looking into it and I hope I clarified my post this way.